# Magento 2 : How to call template file from block file

Tags: php, magento2, block

so I want to call template phtml file from block file directly without attaching them in the layout XML file.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call it without xml why not directly from phtml via

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')
          ->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::template.phtml')
          ->toHtml(); ?>
```

You could probably use the same way in your block though, but I have not tested that.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$content = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template');
$content->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::template.phtml');
$content->toHtml();
```

Comment: No I tried this method but not working for me, if you have another solution that works?